# How do I reach end of file in less terminal without ...skipping

Tags: terminal, less-unix

If I have tree output in terminal with less with this function

```
function tre() {
    tree -aC -I '.git|node_modules|bower_components' --dirsfirst "$@" | less -FRNX;
}
```

, it will scroll 1 line by pressing key each time.

I need a shorcut or command to reach and of file.

If I press "G" the output would be with "...skipping..."

```
     19 │   │   │   └── someotherfile.db
     20 │   │   ├── static
...skipping...
     62 │   │   ├── user
     63 │   │   │   ├── admin.py
```

How do I get to the end of file with all lines loaded without "...skipping..."?

Comment: I can't reproduce that behaviour. Do you have the `$LESS` environment variable set to something special?

Comment: Edited my question and add a function for output tree with less

Comment: Still can't reproduce that, using the exact same command. What version of `less` do you use (`less --version`)?

Comment: [This Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274549/more-less-skipping-when-searching) suggests "Skipping..." shows up when searching.

Comment: Found the solution (posted it below).

Thank your for your attention.

Comment: Could you still tell me what version of `less` you have? I'm curious.

Comment: Sure:
`less 487 (POSIX regular expressions)`

Comment: Hmm. I can't find changes related to `...skipping` between that version and mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with this

```
less -FRNX;
```

The last (X) forced the output line by line. So the solution was not to use it

```
less -FRN;
```

---

(Why I use less for tree output)
On screenshot below is the difference between default *tree* output and output it with *less*. Same folder, but with less output is with *colors*, *line numbers* and *directory first*.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9OHx.jpg)