# Git is showing duplicate "HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD" when I type "git log"

Tags: git

[image]

Why am I seeing twice the entries of "HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD" (I didn't "git commit" twice btw)?

And what that ":...skipping..." line means?

I don't know what to make of this so I don't know what to try.

I've googled to see if anyone has hit this error but I haven't seen it anywhere.

Comment: Hmmmm. What is it?

Comment: I encountered this issue several times. I tried but never found out how to reproduce it. To overcome the issue, I just reopened a terminal or pressed multiple enters and ran `git log` again.

Comment: there may bean issue with your pager interacting with your terminal. Does this happen straight ahead when you type `git log` ? or if you scroll down then up, or mix scrolling within the pager (e.g: press up/down arrows while `less` is open) with scrolling the terminal itself (e.g: using the mousewheel, which may instruct the graphical window of your terminal to scroll its content) ?

Comment: If you run a linux-ey terminal (like `bash` or `zsh` or ...) you may try `Ctrl+L` (which will send a "clear screen" to the terminal). I don't know how `cmd.exe` or `Powershell` beahave, chances are it would work too.

Comment: maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56546050/86072

Answer (score 5):

You're only *seeing* it twice. In reality it's a unique commit (same ID) and it was actually only listed once in the git log.

That's because...

```
...skipping...
```

is the result of scrolling through the output of `git log`'s (default) pager¹ and then *additionally* scrolling back up using the terminal's window/scrollback-buffer.

This is because the pager achieves scrolling up and down and such by rewriting the terminal's screen contents. The `...skipping...` indicates that this happened and that the contents of the file were not displayed in-sequence.

If you use `git log` and don't scroll with your Terminal, but only with <Page Up> and <Page Down> you shouldn't see any duplicate commit.

¹ a pager is a command-line program that let's you navigate/scroll through a program's output